# CEILING and FLOOR function in Fortran - aren't they supposed to return INTEGERS?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

A quick question regarding the `CEILING` and `FLOOR` functions in Fortran 90/95.

Based on the documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CEILING.html

My impression is that they take in REALs, but return INTEGERs. However, as an example, for this simple program, I get:

```
PROGRAM example
REAL:: X=-3.4
nintx = NINT(x)
ceilx = CEILING(X)
floorx = FLOOR(X)
WRITE(*,*) nintx, ceilx, floorx
END PROGRAM
```

I get -3, -3.00000 and -4.00000. But based on the documentation all return types are INTEGERs. So why are the `CEILING` and `FLOOR` results displayed with the decimal point and trailing zeros?

Comment: There are implicitly typed variables `nintx`, `ceilx`, `floorx` and the compiler does the conversions for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`CEILING` and `FLOOR` do return integer results.  However, you are not printing those results: you are printing the variables `celix` and `floorx` which are of real type.

Those variables are real because of implicit typing.  Contrast this with `nintx` which is indeed an integer variable.

List-directed output (the `write(*,*)` part) has as natural result formatting the real variables as you see.  If you instead directly print the function results

```
write(*,*) NINT(x), CEILING(X), FLOOR(X)
```

you will be less surprised.

The obvious thing to say is: don't use implicit typing.  Have as your second line `implicit none`.

Comment: You haven't learned fortran until you can type `implicit none` with your eyes closed.